# How to Force Log Files to cut in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am using a `TimedRotatingFileHandler` inside of a long running application, set to cut log files at midnight. However, if the application has no action, the log file might not cut at midnight, or anytime close to it.

What is the simplest way to *force* a log file to cut at midnight (or any arbitrary time)? I would prefer not to update application code with some internal time dependency. My original thought was to write a script triggered by a cron job to obtain the `logger` instance used by the application, and just trigger a rollover at midnight. Can that be done? Otherwise, can the logger be configured to automatically cut at midnight?

## Application.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("test.log" , 'midnight', 1, backupCount=5, utc=True)
logger.addHandler(handler)

while True:
    if action_required():
       logger.info("Something happened")
    sleep(5)
```

## CutLogs.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
app_logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
app_logger.handlers[0].doRollover()
```

Comment: I would say that adding a thread to your code that checks the time periodically and forces a rollover at midnight would be the easiest and most clear way of doing this.  This does of course add some time dependence to your code, but at least everything is all self contained.

Comment: What about writing a custom signal handler and having a cron job send the process a signal at midnight?

Comment: @amicitas - Both options would work, but management has unfortunately placed a lock on the application software updates. If there isn't an easier solution I'll raise a stink and implement something like that

Comment: What about killing Application.py at midnight, and then restarting it immediately after? Would that force close the log? It is hard to imagine a solution to this without adding a few lines of code to the application.

Comment: @dinkelk Correct, that would also work, except that it could interrupt work in process. I agree with your assessment fully